# Linking SQL Azure and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

In SQL Server you can link another database such as Oracle or Sybase and write queries that span both. Can you do the same thing with SQL Azure and SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

Well - this is a good question. Please see this link where I answered this question on the SQL Azure MSDN forum: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/ssdsgetstarted/thread/5c8cbbb6-9027-4bf4-9239-e6c4cfc3426a

The short answer is that there is a way, but it is not supported. Here is the link that discusses how to make it work: http://sqlcat.com/sqlcat/b/msdnmirror/archive/2011/03/07/linked-servers-to-sql-azure.aspx

Here is the official support team statement regarding the workarount indicating that it is not supported: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2011/05/03/not-linkedservertosqlazure-where-provider-msdasql-and-dsn-sql-server-native-client.aspx